# Python - Integrating entire list with the Gaussian distribution

Tags: python, integration, normal-distribution

I'm trying to plot the integral of this normal distribution for values greater than x defined as

[image]

where

[image]

defining both functions in python

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
import numpy as np

def gaussian(x, mu, sig):
    norm = 1/np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sig*sig)
    return norm * np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2. * sig*sig))

def gaussianGreater(x, mu, sig):
    Integrand = lambda x: gaussian(x, mu, sig)
    return integrate.quad(Integrand,-np.Inf, x)[0]
```

My problem now lies in the integration bounds of my `gaussianGreater` function while it is being evaluated through the distribution function. When evaluating, this occurs.

```
y = gaussianGreater(subdist_1, mu_1, sig_1 )
xd = np.argsort(subdist_1)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(subdist_1[xd] ,y[xd] )

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element
is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried changing the upper bounds to what the error gave me, but that would return the error `'float' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Applying a for loop does not work either

```
[gaussianGreater(x, mu_1, sig_1 ) for x in subdist_1]

TypeError: only integer arrays with one element can be converted to an index
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What behavior do you want exactly? You want the `x` argument to `gaussianGreater` to potentially be a list of values, and to use the greatest of them in the call to `integrate.quad`?

Comment: @SpruceBondera  I'll elaborate better in the edit.  I'm just trying to fix the bounds of integration like the first function I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use [scipy.stats.norm](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html)'s survival function for 1 - F(x):

```
import scipy.stats as ss
x = np.linspace(-3, 3, 100)
y = ss.norm.sf(x)  # you can pass its mean and std. dev. as well
plt.plot(x, y)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So this is effectively the function I have defined in my post but as a callable function from scipy? Just wanting to make sure.

Comment: This is the vectorized version of P(X>x): It means that it calculates the probability of X being greater than a specified x. The difference is, it is vectorized so you can pass an array of x's and it returns an array of the same size with corresponding probabilities. Now that I re-read your question, the integration seems to be for P(X<x) and that is the cdf. You can just change `ss.norm.sf(x)` to `ss.norm.cdf(x)`.

Comment: I see. Again, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

What you've defined will work only when `x` is a single `float`. If what you want is to be able to pass a numpy array, say `np.array([0.2, 0.3])` and get [N(>0.2), N(>0.3)], then you can use the function as you've already defined and just call the `vectorize` method. So if `a` was the numpy array you were using, `a.vectorize(gaussianGreater)` would get you an array with `gaussianGreater` applied to each element. You could define another function, `vectorGausssianGreater` that takes an array and just returns the result of that vectorize call on it. If what you really want is a single function that can take an array value, you could define something like the following:

```
def gaussian_greater(values, mean, standard_deviation):
    def greater_float(upper_bound):
        integrand = lambda y: gaussian(y, mean, standard_deviation)
        return integrate.quad(integrand, -np.inf, upper_bound)[0]
    return values.vectorize(greater)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Looking at the equation now, I should be trying to connect the values in each list by integrating the from negative infinity to that number to get some value, while the same number is still be evaluating through the gaussian function. Any ideas on how to accomplish that?